# jsLint/jsHint maven site reporting

Tags: javascript, maven, jslint, jshint

We are looking to incorporate jsLint or jsHint into our continuous integration process, I have found many maven plugins that will execute jsLint or jsHint and will break the build if the rules have been violated.

We do not, however, have the luxury of fixing all of the discovered issues immediately, so I just want to use jsLint/jsHint to generate reports, rather than break the build.

What I am looking for is a way to have the jsLint/jsHint maven plugin publish the result in the mvn site similar to checkstyle.

If anyone has any ideas or knows of any existing plugins that have this option, it would help a lot.

Already investigated:

- http://mojo.codehaus.org/jslint-maven-plugin/ - goes beyond the basics, but no reporting
- http://code.google.com/p/jslint-maven-plugin/ - fails the build, no reporting

The list goes on, many are similar in what they do, no reporting though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
http://www.dev.abiss.gr/mvn-jstools

Answer (score 0):

[jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/) is configurable to not break the build.

Comment: They all are. I was not asking for configuring it not to break the build, I was asking about how to generate site reports. The url I provided in my solution points to a plugin that does it.

Comment: Ah — my apologies for misreading. Site reports are definitely not something jslint4java does yet.

Comment: I realize I wasn't clear on that point in the original thread. Thanks for reaching out. The solution I found is the answer, however the plugin is not in full release version yet, and not available in any repositories.